# Dynamically create 2 dimensional object Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have kinda a tricky situation where I can't figure out a good solution.
I have an array of the following type:

```
data = [ '1', '1', '964', '718', '0', '0', '0' ];
```

Which is as follows:

*data[0] = slide number*

*data[1] = shape number*

*data[2] = width*

*data[3] = height*

*data[4] = left*

*data[5] = top*

*data[6] = href*

**Explanation**

A slide can have multiple shapes, and each shape has the 5 attributes (width, height, left, top, href).

**Goal**

I want to create a big object which would hold all the data.
Something like this:

```
[{"Slide1" : [{
    "Shape1" : {
      "Width" : 200,
      "Height" : 100,
      "Left" : 200,
      "Top" : 100,
      "Link" : "1"
    }
  }, {
    "Shape2" : {
      "Width" : 200,
      "Height" : 100,
      "Left" : 200,
      "Top" : 100,
      "Link" : "0"
    }
  }]
}, {
  "Slide2" : [{
    "Shape1" : {
      "Width" : 200,
      "Height" : 100,
      "Left" : 200,
      "Top" : 100,
      "Link" : "0"
    }
  }, {
    "Shape2" : {
      "Width" : 200,
      "Height" : 100,
      "Left" : 200,
      "Top" : 100,
      "Link" : "1"
    }
  }, {
    "Shape3" : {
      "Width" : 200,
      "Height" : 100,
      "Left" : 200,
      "Top" : 100,
      "Link" : "2"
    }
  }]
}]
```

I wrote the following code, which almost got me there but, still not close:

```
for(var x = 0; x<data.length; x++){
    data[x] = data[x].slice(1, -1);
    data[x] = data[x].split("#");
}
var count = 0;
var total_slides = 66;
var slidesnr_and_shapesnr = {};
var data_object = {};
while(count < data.length)
{
    slidesnr_and_shapesnr[data[count][0]] = data[count][1];
    count++;
}
for(var i = 1; i<=total_slides; i++){
    for(var j = 1; j <= slidesnr_and_shapesnr[i]; j++){
        for(var k = 0; k<data.length; k++){
            if(data[k][0] == i && data[k][1] == j){
                data_object['slide'+i]['shapes'+j] = {
                    'width': data[k][2],
                    'height': data[k][3],
                    'left': data[k][4],
                    'top': data[k][5],
                    'href': data[k][6]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get *Cannot set property 'shapes1' of undefined* probably because:

`data_object['slide'+i]['shapes'+j] // this line`

Which would be the way I could create the object format I want?

P.S. The data variable is holding multiple arrays which look the same. Is an array within an array.
Some other data for testing would be:

```
[ '1', '1', '964', '718', '0', '0', '0' ]
[ '2', '1', '964', '718', '0', '0', '0' ]
[ '2', '2', '311', '379', '612', '179', '0' ]
[ '2', '3', '35', '39', '36', '694', '0' ]
[ '2', '4', '35', '39', '75', '694', '0' ]
[ '3', '1', '964', '718', '0', '0', '0' ]
[ '3', '2', '116', '137', '46', '598', '16' ]
[ '3', '3', '35', '39', '181', '696', '0' ]
[ '3', '4', '35', '39', '220', '696', '0' ]
[ '3', '5', '35', '39', '259', '696', '0' ]
[ '3', '6', '35', '39', '297', '696', '0' ]
[ '3', '7', '35', '39', '337', '696', '0' ]
[ '3', '8', '51', '51', '658', '541', '0' ]
[ '3', '9', '51', '51', '787', '541', '0' ]
[ '4', '1', '964', '718', '0', '0', '0' ]
[ '4', '2', '116', '137', '46', '598', '62' ]
[ '4', '3', '35', '39', '181', '696', '0' ]
[ '4', '4', '35', '39', '221', '696', '0' ]
[ '4', '5', '35', '39', '260', '696', '0' ]
[ '4', '6', '35', '39', '298', '696', '0' ]
[ '4', '7', '56', '56', '894', '260', '0' ]
[ '5', '1', '964', '718', '0', '0', '0' ]
[ '5', '2', '116', '137', '46', '598', '24' ]
[ '5', '3', '35', '39', '181', '696', '0' ]
[ '5', '4', '35', '39', '298', '696', '0' ]
[ '5', '5', '35', '39', '221', '696', '0' ]
[ '5', '6', '35', '39', '260', '696', '0' ]
```

Comment: The data structure you would like to construct seems to have one unnecessary nested object. You don't need an object with a single property called Shape#. I would simply make the Slide# array 2D instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in front of the offending line:

```
if (!data_object['slide'+i]) {
  data_object['slide'+i] = {};
}
```